# Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm really new to Spring and Maven and I wanted to create an environment specific build. The main idea was to create profiles in maven and the profile set some variables to help to load the proper property file.

Here is one of my profile in maven:

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <env>dev</env>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

And here is my FTPProperties class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/properties/ftp-${env}.properties")
public class FTPProperties {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private String server;

    public FTPProperties() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        this.server = environment.getProperty("ftp.server");
    }

    public String getServer() {
        return server;
    }
}
```

When I try to build it I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'env' in string value "classpath:/properties/ftp-${env}.properties"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

Deleted the FTPProperties class and moved the configuration to applicationContext.xml like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/properties/ftp-${env}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And i just updated my Maven profiles:

```
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <env>dev</env>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

After this i've created a FTPService class:

```
@Service
public class FTPService {

@Value("${ftp.server}")
private String server;

public String getServer() {
    return server;
}
}
```

Everything is working perfectly as intended.